# Splitting a JSON key based on regex to store in multiple variables

Tags: c#, json.net

```
{"key":"abc/1"}
```

I want to store the value in two fields instead of one. I can do the following.

```
[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "key", Required = Required.Always)]
public string Value { get; set; }
```

However, I want to have two fields but use `JsonProperty`to serialize and deserialize them as a combined string. For example, if I define the following fields:

```
public string ValueScope { get; set; }
public int ValueId { get; set; }
```

I want to use JsonProperty or any other tag to populate the fields while deserializing. Is it possible to do that, i.e. populate ValueScope as "abc" and ValueId as 1 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can actually implement the `get` and `set` of the 2 properties to just manipulate the underlying `JsonProperty`.

Here's a quick example of how you might go about it (warning: I just wrote this out in notepad, so please excuse any typos).

```
public string ValueScope
{
    get
    {
        var values = (this.Value ?? "").Split('/');
        if (values.Length == 2)
            return values[0];
        else
            return null;
    }
    set
    {
        this.Value = (value ?? "") + "/" + this.ValueId.ToString();
    }
}

public int ValueId
{
    get
    {
        int currentValue;
        var values = (this.Value ?? "").Split('/');
        if (values.Length == 2 && int.TryParse(values[1], out currentValue))
            return currentValue;
        else
            return default(int);
    }
    set
    {
        this.Value = (this.ValueScope ?? "") + "/" + value.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: So you mean I should keep three fields, Value, ValueScope and ValueId, right ? I wanted to do it with two only.

Comment: To make it work with only 2 fields, I suppose you'd have to implement your own `JsonConverterAttribute` out of json.net that has a parameter for the name of the other property, then add `JsonIgnore` to the other property, but I'm not sure honestly how the deserialization might work for that. Otherwise, you might have to consider your own `JsonSerializer` which is much more tightly coupled (http://blog.maskalik.com/asp-net/json-net-implement-custom-serialization/).

Comment: Also, here's the docs on implementing your own JsonSerializer - http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm

Comment: Actually, callbacks might be more helpful in this scenario.